# Using WordNet and the program NLTK on Python, how can I check how many lemmas each language has in WordNet?

Tags: nltk, wordnet, lemmatization

Using WordNet and the program NLTK on Python, how can I check how many lemmas each language has in WordNet? I am looking for code that tells me the number of lemmas per language in WordNet. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

I have tried using the code: "print('Number of lemmas per language:')"

The output is consistently "Number of lemmas per language:
Ellipsis"